# Own eclipse plugin - sharing data between plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would like to write small eclipse plugin for code estimation. At start I would like to use results shown in "problems" tab (warnings and errors) instead of writing next, own tool for code analysis. The question is: 
Is it possible to use data from one plugin in another? 
I would be greatful for any examples or links to tutorials.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Yes, you can use data from another plugin provided that it defines an API for you to use. What exactly is it you want?

Comment: I would like to get the list of all warnings and errors (their descripion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects in the Problems view are called 'markers' and are represented by the `org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker` interface.

You get the markers defined on a file, folder or project by calling the `findMarkers` method on the `IResource`. You can ask for all types of marker or just specific types.